# Tabbed Activity template Android 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

I apologise in advance if this question is NOT as interesting as others might expect. Firstly there are not that many answers to questions about the most recent version of Android Studio (that is version 2.1.2). Also I have noticed people seldom use the templates provided by the IDE(I believe its there to speed up the development process).

How do I modify the code for the Tabbed Activity template? I am currently staring at the code generated by the IDE for the template. I am clueless how to modfiy it to include the fragments for the three sections it has by default. I have gone over the code and to some extent understand the structure and what the parts do, but it does so in a way that is completely different from how the official docs tell people to do it from scratch.

I have created one Fragment and hope to create two more. How do I place them inside the tabs, using the template?

Can someone please put me through and also direct me to useful materials in this regard?

Ok from the current structure, I can see that in the .java file there is code for the Activity and the default Fragment(called as placeholder fragment). I have tried to replace the default Fragment with one of my Fragment by calling it in the onCreateView(). The thing is how do I add other Fragments. The template code:

.java file

```
package name;
public class myUI extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_UI);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my_UI, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_UI, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

It is this .java file that has me thinking, there is only one Fragment XML layout but it appears that a trick is being used to replicate it across the three tabs(along with the TextView component in it). 
My question is this, I have my own Fragments created (with their own behaviours), how do I make them part of the TabbedActivity? In what part of its code do I put it? Also if it is not to much trouble can someone explain what is actually goin on in the code(I mean the area where one Fragment is appears three times)?

The XML Layout for the Activity itself is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.myProject.myProject.MyUI">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: "How do I modify the code for the Tabbed Activity template?" -- since the templates vary by Android Studio release, please edit your question to include the code that confuses you, pointing out specifically what you do not understand. That way, this question will benefit others as well as you, today and in the future. Besides, few people have the code for this template memorized.

Comment: You haven't included any code sample! I suggest you reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. I will paste the code and explain in detail. Let me modify my post.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone else (since this question is one year old, I bet you already figured it out). It's actually not that difficult. The template is overwhelming at first, but with enough attention you can understand it. Anyway, here it goes:

First thing I noticed is this piece of code:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "SECTION 1";
        case 1:
            return "SECTION 2";
        case 2:
            return "SECTION 3";
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you change the return under **getCount()** to, say, 2; and delete the **case 2:** under **getPageTitle(int position)**, the activity shows only two tabs.

The objects get called in this order: First, **SectionsPageAdapter** get instantiated in **onCreate()**. This ends up calling this method:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
```

As you can see, this asks **PlaceholderFragment** for a new instance for every tab you have specified. No need to change anything here. Now let's go to **PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(int sectionNumber)**...

```
/**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

So, it seems like it defines an argument (sectionNumber), sets it and returns the fragment. No need to change anything here either. Then, it looks like it depends on the only method we haven't looked at yet: **onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)**. And it makes sense, since it takes as an argument the Bundle argument. Let's take a look:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
```

The contents of every fragment are defined here. So, it would make sense to make your changes here.

This is an example of how I changed it for my project:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;
        TextView textView;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infraestructuras, container, false);
                textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label1);
                textView.setText("Infraestructuras");
                return rootView;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_incidentes, container, false);
                textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label2);
                textView.setText("Incidentes");
                return rootView;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I created a new layout for each tab.